# Within group variation

Tags: statistical-significance

I would like to measure the within group variation of some values. I understand the calculation behind that process but is there any statistical test that determines yes this variance is significant? A chi square test maybe?

I don’t want compare between groups, that would simply be an anova. I am strictly focusing on with in group variation.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to construct the null hypothesis for such test? Does the ANOVA setup consist independent groups or repeated measures? If you want to test whether the population variance for a particular group (within-group) is equal to a prespecified value, a Chi square test for variance would suffice, assuming the groups are independent. For repeated measure ANOVA, Mauchly's test for sphericity can be applied for within-groups.